# how to wait for an async call in azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-async

I am trying to call face api async method from an Azure function. I am awaiting on an async method but Azure function goes off and completes it. How can I wait for the async operation to complete in Azure fucntion?

Here's my code (I am using VS 2017, .Net standard 2.0):

```
public static class IdentifyHttp
{
    [FunctionName("IdentifyHttp")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


        string url = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();            

        //string url = req.Query["url"];

        Stream rtn = null;
        HttpWebRequest aRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse aResponse = (HttpWebResponse)aRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(aResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);

            rtn = sReader.BaseStream;           

        AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync(rtn);

        return url != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {url}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }

    private static async void AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync(Stream s)
    {

        string PersonGroupId = "employees";
        FaceServiceClient FaceServiceAPIClient = new FaceServiceClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0");
        string name = "No one identified";

        //s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var faces = await FaceServiceAPIClient.DetectAsync(s);
        var faceIds = faces.Select(face => face.FaceId).ToArray();

        var results = await FaceServiceAPIClient.IdentifyAsync(PersonGroupId, faceIds);
        foreach (var identifyResult in results)
        {
            if (identifyResult.Candidates.Length > 0)
            {
                var candidateId = identifyResult.Candidates[0].PersonId;
                var person = await FaceServiceAPIClient.GetPersonAsync(PersonGroupId, candidateId);
                name = person.Name;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `public static async <IActionResult> Run` for the main function signature. `private static async Task AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync` for your method signature and `await AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync(rtn);` inside your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the function with `async Task AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync` instead of `async void AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync`. In case of any errors in `AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync` they are not populated to your main function and you have to await your own function with: `await AnalyzeImageFaceAPIAsync(rtn);`